# GCP Dataflow Error: Path "gs://..." is not a valid filepattern. The pattern must be of the form "gs://<bucket>/path/to/file"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to create a dataflow from Pub-Sub to BigQuery in GCP console.

In the "Create job from template" screen, I am having a trouble what to enter for "Temporary Location" box. It says "Path and filename prefix for writing temporary files. ex: gs://MyBucket/tmp".

So I specified something like this: "gs://${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}-test/dataflow/tmp"

But I am getting this error (dataflow folder is there BTW):

```
Path "gs://${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}-test/dataflow/tmp" is not a valid  filepattern. The pattern must be of the form "gs://<bucket>/path/to/file".
```

I tried different patterns but to no avail. Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it complains that it wants a bucket ...

> The pattern must be of the form "gs:// [bucket] /path/to/file".

```
export PROJECT_ID=$(gcloud config list --format 'value(core.project)')
export BUCKET_NAME="${PROJECT_ID}-test"

gsutil "gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/dataflow/tmp"
```

wondered about the `-test` suffix and I've just tried to reflect that in code.

one can obtain all valid `BUCKET_NAME`s with `gsutil ls`.

Comment: That's a valid point. The bucket named "${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}-test" is there but then I realized that this macro is not recognized there different from what this doc says (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/modern-data-pipeline-firestore-bigquery-dataflow-templates/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fcloud#8). When I entered the bucket name itself without the macro, it worked! Thanks!